# Finding the mean and standard deviation of a timedelta object in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean, timedelta

I would like to calculate the `mean` and `standard deviation` of a `timedelta` by bank from a `dataframe` with two columns shown below. When I run the code (also shown below) I get the below error:

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

My dataframe:

```
   bank                          diff
   Bank of Japan                 0 days 00:00:57.416000
   Reserve Bank of Australia     0 days 00:00:21.452000
   Reserve Bank of New Zealand  55 days 12:39:32.269000
   U.S. Federal Reserve          8 days 13:27:11.387000
```

My code:

```
means = dropped.groupby('bank').mean()
std = dropped.groupby('bank').std()
```

Comment: How do you want to aggregate the `timedelta` object? Access the `.days` or `.seconds` attributes if you're looking to aggregate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to convert `timedelta` to some numeric value, e.g. `int64` by `values` what is most accurate, because convert to `ns` is what is the numeric representation of `timedelta`:

```
dropped['new'] = dropped['diff'].values.astype(np.int64)

means = dropped.groupby('bank').mean()
means['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(means['new'])

std = dropped.groupby('bank').std()
std['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(std['new'])
```

Another solution is to convert values to `seconds` by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), but that is less accurate:

```
dropped['new'] = dropped['diff'].dt.total_seconds()

means = dropped.groupby('bank').mean()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm -- (I used the first solution)!

Comment: Can you tell why the second solution is less accurate?

Answer (score 32):

Pandas `mean()` and other aggregation methods support `numeric_only=False` parameter.

```py
dropped.groupby('bank').mean(numeric_only=False)
```

Found here: [Aggregations for Timedelta values in the Python DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239742/aggregations-for-timedelta-values-in-the-python-dataframe)

Comment: This is way more elegant, and IMO should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 11):

No need to convert `timedelta` back and forth.  Numpy and pandas can seamlessly do it for you with a faster run time.  Using your `dropped` `DataFrame`:

```py
import numpy as np

grouped = dropped.groupby('bank')['diff']

mean = grouped.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
std = grouped.apply(lambda x: np.std(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest passing the `numeric_only=False` argument to `mean` as mentioned by Alexander Usikov - this works for pandas version 0.20+.

If you have an older version, the following works:

```
import pandas pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'td': pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(days=i) for i in range(5)]),
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
})

(
    df
    .astype({'td': int})         # convert timedelta to integer (nanoseconds)
    .groupby('group')
    .mean()
    .astype({'td': 'timedelta64[ns]'})
)
```