# Pandas Dataframe Timedelta mean() not showing correct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

I've searched and searched and haven't found a solution or just an answer to why this is happening.

I'm trying to determine the `mean()` per Borough for `Request_Closing_Time` in my pandas dataframe.  When I `groupby` Borough and then get the mean for Request Closing Time I'm getting very large values, `13` to `44` days and then even `87,426` days for one result.  The max value is only `24` days and the average for the whole dataframe is only `4` hours.  If I single out an individual Borough with the get_group command then I seem to get a more normal answer which I believe is correct.

Any ideas as to why values for mean are so far off when `groupby` is by Borough only?

```py
In [283]:nyc_sr_calls_trimmed.describe()
Out[283]:        Unique Key     Request_Closing_Time       Incident Zip
         count  3.006980e+05    298534  298083.000000
         mean   3.130054e+07    0 days 04:18:51.832782865   10848.888645
         std    5.738547e+05    0 days 06:05:22.141833856   583.182081
         min    3.027948e+07    0 days 00:01:00 83.000000
         25%    3.080118e+07    0 days 01:16:33 10310.000000
         50%    3.130436e+07    0 days 02:42:55.500000  11208.000000
         75%    3.178446e+07    0 days 05:21:00 11238.000000
         max    3.231065e+07    24 days 16:52:22    11697.000000

In [284]: nyc_sr_calls_trimmed['Request_Closing_Time'].mean()
Out[284]:Timedelta('0 days 04:18:51.832782865')

In [285]:by_burrough = nyc_sr_calls_trimmed.groupby(['Borough'])
         by_burrough['Request_Closing_Time'].mean(numeric_only=None).dt.floor('s')

Out[285]:Borough
         BRONX              -13 days +03:21:47
         BROOKLYN           -13 days +03:18:24
         MANHATTAN          -36 days +14:38:51
         QUEENS             -16 days +07:37:05
         STATEN ISLAND      -44 days +22:01:24
         Unspecified     -87426 days +14:15:03
         Name: Request_Closing_Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [286]:b = by_burrough.get_group('QUEENS')
         b['Request_Closing_Time'].mean(numeric_only=False)

Out[286]:Timedelta('0 days 04:52:16.450111002')
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure what i'm not thinking of or accounting for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"If I single out an individual Borough with the get_group command then I seem to get a more normal answer which I believe is correct".*

Since you mentioned the above, something I would try is to get the mean of `Request_Closing_Time` for each Borough individually, as follows:

```
by_burrough["Request_Closing_Time"].apply(lambda df_group: df_group.mean(numeric_only=False))
```

or

```
by_burrough.apply(lambda df_group: df_group["Request_Closing_Time"].mean(numeric_only=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `.describe()` on timedelta dtype columns was outrageous, just as you saw.
I found this can be addressed with `numeric_only=False`, as answered already and per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239742/aggregations-for-timedelta-values-in-the-python-dataframe).

However, I am using Dask and Dask doesn't support `numeric_only=False`.

So, my solution was to convert my datetimes to int
`df[col].astype('int64')//1e9  # convert to secs since epoch (1970)`

then subtract from each other and then average.

The full solution:

```py
def convert_datetime_col_as_day_since_epoch(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.concat([
        df, 
        *[
            pd.DataFrame({f"{col}_epoch": df[col].astype('int64')//1e9//(24 * 60 * 60)}, dtype='int64')
            for col, dtype in df.dtypes.to_dict().items() if dtype == '<M8[ns]'
        ],
    ], axis=1)

df = df.map_partitions(convert_datetime_col_as_day_since_epoch)

df['DATETIME_DIFF'] = df['DATE1_epoch'] - df['DATE2_epoch']

df.describe()
```