# How to convert timedelta to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I try to convert timedelta into datetime to get then an excel with `hh:mm:ss` format, but I don't achieve this.

I have an extract of dataframe `df_abc` that looks like this (the data is a `timedelta`):

```
0 days 01:20:34
0 days 01:20:24
0 days 01:20:24
0 days 01:20:23
```

My goal is to compute the mean of these data and to save it on an excel file with `hh:mm:ss` format.
When I save dates like `0 days 01:20:34` on excel, it writes only a number of days (ex : `0.05`, instead of `01:20:34`).

I achieved to convert it to datetime by using :

```
pd.to_datetime(df_abc).dt.time
```

But to compute the mean of these durations:

- When I try

  ```
  pd.to_datetime(df_abc).dt.time.mean()
  ```

  it gives this error:

  ```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
  ```
- When I try

  ```
  df_abc.mean()
  ```

  it gives this error:

  ```
  TypeError: Could not convert 0 days 05:21:45 to numeric
  ```

I solved it by using : `mean_df_abc = pd.to_timedelta(df_abc).mean()`.

=> **So, now I want to convert : `Timedelta('0 days 01:20:26.250000')` into datetime**, because `timedelta` format can't be printed on excel like `hh:mm:ss`.

```
pd.to_datetime(mean_df_abc).dt.time
```

provides this error:

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Have you an idea of what can be done to solve this problem ? (perhaps another way to save on excel with `hh:mm:ss` format ?)

Comment: When I try : `pd._to_datetime(df_abc).dt.mean()`, I get the following error : AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_to_datetime'

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid and didn't have a real look to the error ^^ So I rather have this error : TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616546/finding-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-of-a-timedelta-object-in-pandas-df

Comment: I finally solved my problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101432/timedelta-to-string-type-in-pandas-dataframe. Thank you for your help !